# Which attribute is applied if both id and class are specified for an element and why?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>My Social Network</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="best_friend" class="friend" ></div>
        <div class="family"></div>
        <div class="enemy" id="archnemesis"></div>

    </body>
</html>


div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border: 2px solid black;

}

#best_friend {
 border: 4px solid #00C957;   
}

.friend {
 border: 2px dashed #008000;   
}

.family {

 border: 2px dashed #0000FF;   

}

.enemy {
  border: 2px dashed #FF0000;   

}

#archnemesis {
 border: 4px solid #CC0000;   
}
```

My question is: Notice how I define `border` for both `class` and `id`. The `border` that is applied is the one coming from the `id`. Why so? Why is the `border` specification in `id` overriding the one in `class`.

Comment: `id` has a higher priority over `class`. Also anything that is defined later in css will take precedence.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser determines which styles to apply in what order based on **Specificity**, the higher number determines which will be applied.

Universal selectors have a specificity of 0,0,0,0.
`*` = **0**

HTML selectors have a specificity of 1.
`p`, `div`, etc.. = **1 each**

So each HTML selector adds to the specificity.
`div p` = **2**, `div p span` = **3**

Class selectors have a specificity of 10.
`.class` = **10**

Class selectors combined with HTML selectors.
`div p.class` = **12**

ID selectors have a specificity value of 100.
`#id` = **100**

ID selectors combined with HTML selectors.
`#id div` = **101**

`!important` overrides all other styles unless combined with another selector.
`table td {height: 50px !important;}` Would override any `height` style applied to only a `td` within a `table`.

Inline styles have the highest specificity of 1000.
`style=` = **1000**

### **Useful resources**

[CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
[Specificity | HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/)

Answer (score 2):

Without including exceptions (e.g. `:not`, `!important`), the following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:

[image: specificity]

1. Universal selectors (e.g., *) (**lowest**)
2. Type selectors (e.g., h1)
3. Class selectors (e.g., .example)
4. Attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"])
5. Pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover)
6. ID selectors (e.g., #example)
7. Inline style (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") (**highest**)

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

---

> The border that is applied is the one coming from the id. Why so? Why is the border specification in id overriding the one in class.

From this list, you can see that `id` is higher than `class`, so the border set in `id` will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

id has more priority than class.

Comment: Seems you got here late, this was already stated in the previous answers/comments.

Answer (score 1):

Following rules are applied for css

1.) When more than 1 overlapping styles are applied to the same element, only the last style is visible

2.) When the `!important` attribute is used, it has the highest priority

**3.)** The style that has the highest CSS specificity is applied. The specificity of different elements is defined as follows:

**ID attribute = 100 

   Class attribute = 10 

   Element = 1**

Refer [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Because `id` has a higher precedence than `class` you can verify that in [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**Specificity hierarchy**

Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy. There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector:

1. Inline styles (Presence of style in document).
   An inline style lives within your XHTML document. It is attached directly to the element to be styled. E.g. `<h1 style="color: #fff;">`
2. IDs (# of ID selectors)
   ID is an identifier for your page elements, such as `#div`.
3. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes (# of class selectors).
   This group includes `.classes, [attributes]` and pseudo-classes such as `:hover, :focus` etc.
4. Elements and pseudo-elements (# of Element (type) selectors).
   Including for instance `:before` and `:after`.

Ref:http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

and here : http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/css-specificity-id-overrides